# Java: String manipulation. Fetch last subpath in a URL

Tags: java, string, split, substring

Lets say I have a URL `http://example.com/files/public_files/test.zip` and I want to extract the last subpath so `test.zip`, How would I be able do this?

I am from Python so I am still new to Java and learning. In Python you could do something like this:

```
>>> x = "http://example.com/files/public_files/test.zip"
>>> x.split("/")[-1]
'test.zip'
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways. I prefer:

```
String url = "http://example.com/files/public_files/test.zip";
String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using String class method is a way to go. But given that you are having a URL, you can use [`java.net.URL.getFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getFile%28%29):

```
String url = "http://example.com/files/public_files/test.zip";
String filePart = new URL(url).getFile();
```

---

The above code will get you complete path. To get the file name, you can make use of [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) - [`FilenameUtils.getName()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html):

```
String url = "http://example.com/files/public_files/test.zip";
String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(url);
```

Well, if you don't want to refer to 3rd party library for this task, String class is still an option to go for. I've just given another way.

Comment: You have to handle the `MalformedURLException`, and this actually returns `/files/public_files/test.zip`

Comment: @jlordo. Too bad. There is no method to get the file name. :(

Comment: @jlordo. Found one in Apache Commons. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following:

```
String url = "http://example.com/files/public_files/test.zip";
String arr[] = url.split("/");
String name = arr[arr.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Most similar to the python syntax is :

```
String url = "http://example.com/files/public_files/test.zip";
String [] tokens = url.split("/");
String file = tokens[tokens.length-1];
```

Java lacks the convenient [-n] nth to last selector that Python has. If you wanted to do it all in one line, you'd have to do something gross like this:

```
String file = url.split("/")[url.split("/").length-1];
```

I don't recommend the latter